# How to propose a new site on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

I created an account on area 51 for a new proposal. But after I created and verified my account there is no option for propose a new site? Do we need more reputations to make proposals. How could i propose a new site?

Comment: You should probably improve the description of your new proposal, "for peoples who are introverts" doesn't give a clear indication of what sort of questions should be asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you scroll to the bottom of the home page, you should see:

> Can't find what you're looking for? Select a category listing to the left and propose your site there!

After selecting one and scrolling to the bottom of that page, I see:

> Can't find what you're looking for? Propose a new <subject> site.

…where the latter sentence is a link. Clicking on that should bring you to a form where you can propose a new site.

Comment: ok.. i got it.. could we propose more than one site?

Comment: @user3705625 Yes, you can propose more than one site.